# Remove `target` folders in all subfolders

Tags: bash, directory, rm, macos

I need to remove a `target` folder in all subfolders.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Expecting it should be easy like `rm -r target` but no luck yet.

Comment: Looks like I'm enough with one level removal `rm -r **/target`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

based on comments on this question, it is better to fully use the wide functionality of the `find` command and skip piping altogether (also telling `find` not to descend into directory it's going to ask `rm` to delete):

```
find . -type d -name target -prune -exec rm -r {} +
```

Should work fine for you.

Sorry all, for posting an unsatisfying answer. Your feedback has been very informative.

---

Original answer:

With a little google-fu to [list all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14827686/8171835) and [pipe to rm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307392/8171835):

```
find . -type d | grep -E '/target$' | xargs rm -r
```

Should work. Check whether `find . -type d | grep -E '/target$'` gives the expected output before you remove the folders! Better be save than sorry.

Comment: This would delete any directory that contains the string `target` in its name! For example, `not-target`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kusalananda! I totally forgot about that.. The answer is now modified to use regular expressions and check for an end-of-line.

Comment: Why not use `-name target` with `find`?

Comment: And `-exec`, still with `find`...

Answer (score 8):

If you know you won't have more than a few thousands of these `target` directories, you may set the `globstar` and `dotglob` shell options in `bash` with

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob
```

and then use

```bash
rm -rf ./**/target/
```

This would delete any directory called `target` in or below the current directory.  The slash at the end is crucial as the pattern may otherwise match things that are not directories.

The `**` pattern is enabled by setting the `globstar` shell option, and matches "recursively" down into subdirectories.  Since `dotglob` is also set, this would find directories called `target` beneath hidden subdirectories as well (just like `find` would do).

On macOS, the *default* `bash` is too old to support the `globstar` shell option, so there you may want to install the most recent `bash` using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), or switch to `zsh` (which currently is the default shell for new macOS user accounts).

With `zsh`, you'd do this operation with

```sh
rm -rf ./**/target(/D)
```

Where `(/D)` means "match only directories and include hidden directories".  The `**` glob is enabled by default in `zsh`.

---

With `find`:

```
find . -depth -type d -name target -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This would find all the `target` directories located in or below the current directory, and then call `rm -rf` with as many as possible of these at a time to delete them.  The `-depth` option makes `find` do a depth-first search (we want this to avoid trying to search directories that we've just deleted).

This would be the command you would use if you were using `sh` as the shell (which does not have `**`), or if you have many thousands of such directories.

Even if you have a large number of `target` directories, you should still be able to delete them one by one with

```bash
for dirpath in ./**/target/; do
    rm -rf "$dirpath"
done
```

although this would be slower than using `find` since you are calling `rm` once for every directory.

Comment: As the poster specified the tag `macos`, there is a good chance that `globstar` doesn't work for them. Nonetheless a very full and interesting answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Pudding Thanks for the heads-up about that. I have modified the answer.